# How can I mock the parameters for a controller method using Spring MVC 3.1.x and spring-test-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test-mvc

Using Spring MVC 3.1.x and spring-test-mvc, I was wondering if there is a way to mock the parameters of a function being mapped using @RequestMapping. Please see the code snippet below. I would like to know if I can use spring-test-mvc and mock out the response method below. I know that I can create an instance of the controller class, and then pass in mocked values of the request/response, but that doesn't test out the annotated portions of the code, which is why I would like to know if there is a way to do this using spring-test-mvc. If that is not possible, then is there another way that I can verify that the OutputStream is returning the correct results?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getRequest(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response){
    try{
        String destination = destinationRetrievalService.getDestination(request, response);
        InputStream input = httpServletRequestDelegationService.delegateGet(request, destination, response);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        LOG.error("An exception has been thrown while trying to copy the stream back to the page.", ioe);           
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Juan

Comment: What is it you want to do with the mocks?

Comment: I wanted to mock the response so that I can replace the output stream in the ServletResponse with my own ByteArrayOutputStream and validate that the stream coming from the service is in fact what I'm expecting back.

Comment: Can you upgrade to Spring 3.2? The MVC test suite provides methods/objects to do that directly. See the `MockMvcResultMatchers` class.

Comment: I was considering that because of the integration of spring-test-mvc into the spring-test project in 3.2, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this in 3.1 before I would go ahead.

Comment: I just ended up testing the controller by creating an instance of it, and calling the controller method. This doesn't test out the annotation bit, but it allows me to validate the outputstream. I then used spring-text-mvc to test out that my content-type was valid. If anyone finds a way using spring-test-mvc to validate the outputstream content, please answer the question. I will leave it open for now.